# Avoid class selector repetitions in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator

Suppose you have `n` different angular components all requiring a common class selector `"A"`, like:

```
<component-i class="A"></component-i>
```

A simple out-of-the-box approach could be to add said class to the decorator [`@Component`'s](https://angular.io/api/core/Component) [`host`](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#host) key as `host: {'class': 'A'}`, in every single component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'component-i',
  templateUrl: './ui.component-i.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ui.component-i.sass'],
  host: {'class': 'A'}
})
```

This would redound the line `host: {'class': 'A'}` `n` times.

I *believe* that this would be a bad design, and I'm trying to find ways to avoid such code redundancy.

My current idea is to create a decorator `@CustomComponent` that wraps `@Component` in such a way that the redundancy would be dropped in a fashion similar to:

```
import { Component, TypeDecorator} from '@angular/core';

function CustomComponent(data:object):TypeDecorator {
  let my_class:string = "A"
  let host:object = data["host"] || {};
  let class_:string = host["class"] || '';
  host["class"]=class_+my_class;
  data["host"] = host;
  return Component(data);
}

@CustomComponent({
  selector: 'component-i',
  templateUrl: './component-i.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component-i.sass']
})
export class ComponentI {}
```

Is this approach correct? There are other, cleaner, approaches?

Comment: Please remember to explain downvotes, so that the question may be bettered. I am not learning only by watching the vote count go down.

Comment: No explanation of downvotes is required or should be expected.  Simply put, someone felt the question was "not clear or not useful".  Given how vague the question is, I would guess "not clear".

Comment: Thank you, I'll refactor the question. I believed it was clear enough.

Comment: Is the question now clearer? Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think it is better, yes (bear in mind, I wasn't one of the original downvoters, and very few people go back and review their downvotes later to see if they should remove them).

Comment: also, I've never run into this particular issue in angular, so I don't really know an appropriate appropriate approach here :/

Comment: I didn't downvote you either, but it is still not clear to me - are you saying you would like to use `host: {'class': 'A'}` in the Component decorator. It does not appear to support it out of the box, but there is the [:host pseudo-selector](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host) which is used in component.css

Comment: @eric99 I believe you are mistaken, from [the documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#host) it is clear that host is supported out of the box, and I've been using it. Thank you for you comment, I'll further edit the question in order to clear out the doubts that it rouse for you.

Comment: Indeed I am mistaken, Component  inherits it from Directive. So, still struggling to understand your problem.

Comment: @eric99 I have edited the question so to include an example of implementation of  a '@Component' decorator wrapper, so to avoid redounding the `host` key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you can use base class for your components:

```
abstract class Component
{
    @HostBinding('class.A')
    public classEnabled:boolean = true;

    //or

    @HostBinding('class')
    public classNames:string = 'A';
}

class MyComponent extends Component {}
```